# .style is not working in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I've created a canvas element with the id="game-display" in a html file. The yellow border is being shown but what I want to do is to change the border with JavaScript:

```css
#game-display {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="game-display" width="800px" height="400px"></canvas>
```

So in the Js file I've set:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('game-display');
canvas.style.border = "1px solid red";
```

```css
#game-display {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="game-display" width="800px" height="400px"></canvas>
```

But when I run my site, the border keeps yellow.
So I've typed canvas in the console. And it presented the right element.
But when I type canvas.style all the strings are not defined, but that's not true because the yellow border is being shown ):
It's like the .style was not working. 
I use google chrome in it's last version

Comment: I edited your question so the example code you posted runs in a snippet and it seems to work fine

Comment: How is your javascript added to your page?? @sorH

Comment: Seconding what @j08691 -- seems to work fine in the snippet.  My guess is that your JS is executing/evaluating before the `<canvas>` element is actually in the DOM... **OR** never evaluating at all.

Comment: As to why the border styles don't appear on the `style` object, they're not supposed to. The `style` object for an element shows only the styles set *directly* on the element, and none of the styles implied by CSS stylesheet rules.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what happening, since you have kept the script before the canvas and you are not waiting for the DOM to load. You'll have to either wait for DOM load or put your script below in the body.

Otherwise `style` will be `null`.

```css
#game-display {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('game-display');
    canvas.style.border = "1px solid red";
  }
</script>
<canvas id="game-display" width="800px" height="400px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Actually my script tag is just before the body closing tag </body> ):

Comment: can you update the question with whatever code you have, whatever order, just post it.